# How to make all div height inside a row div similar height to the first child of row

Tags: javascript

**I want to change all div inside row be similar to the height of firstchild of `row2`** also if the classes are outside of row the div height will be auto and not be change. *what's the problem in my code can anyone explain also I dont want to change it from css.*

```
var lgh , lgh_in,mdh,mdh_in,smh,smh_in;
    var r = ".row2 >";             
    var z = ['.lg','.lg-in','.md','.md-in','.sm','.sm-in',];
    z.forEach(function (x){
    var xx = document.querySelectorAll( r + x );
    for ( var j = 0; j < xx.length; j++) {
        var ch = document.getElementsByClassName('row2');
        for(var i = 0 ; i < ch.length ; i++ ){
             var ar = ['lg','lg-in','mdh','md-in','sm','sm-in'];   //these are class names , if I put this into my div the div height should be change according to mdh ,lgh ,smh .... etc
             for(var k = 0; k < ar.length;k++){
                 if(ch[i].firstChild.className === ar[k]){                    
                   lgh = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight/ 1.5 ;
 lgh_in = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight - lgh ;
 mdh = lgh/ 1.5 ;
 mdh_in = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight - mdh ;
 smh = mdh/ 1.5 ;
 smh_in = ch[i].parentNode.clientHeight - smh ;
var colors = {}; 
colors[ar[0]] = lgh;
colors[ar[1]] = lgh_in;
colors[ar[2]] = mdh;
colors[ar[3]] = mdh_in;
colors[ar[4]] = smh;
colors[ar[5]] = smh_in;


ch[i].firstChild.style.height = mdh + "px";   //if I remove the px then output is different also         
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = mdh ;   // only for output checking 
if (ch[i].parentNode.tagName === "BODY") {
ch[i].style.height = "auto";     // if the div2 parent is body then height will be auto. 
}

                 }              
             }   
        }        
    }
});
```

**so I able to change the first child div but I cant change  all div inside of the `row2` which is my problem**,

**HTML**

```
<div class="main"><div class="row2"><div class="lg">xfghjgjgx</div><div class="lg-in">xfgvcbvx</div></div>
<div class="row2"><div class="lg-in">xfghjgjgx</div><div class="lg">xfgvcbvx</div></div>
```

Comment: What about your html?

Comment: html updated @br3t

Comment: Is it wrong example or you really have several `row2` in your html?

Comment: `.row2{
 clear:both;
 min-height:auto;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is easier.. Id do something like this?

```
      // For each .box element
  $('.box').each(function() {
    // Set up the variables
    var $this = $(this),
        w = $this.find('img').width(), // Width of the image inside .box
        h = $this.find('img').height(); // Height of the image inside .box
    $this.width(w).height(h); // Set width and height of .box to match image
  });
```

Comment: NO jquery please i want js

Answer (score 0):

Variant with same height of all blocks ( https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/fmovbtp1/ )

```
var classes = ["lg", "lg-in", "md"];
var requiredHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".row2 .lg")).height;

classes.forEach(function(cls) {
    document.querySelectorAll("." + cls).forEach(function(item) {
        item.style.height = requiredHeight;
    });
});
```

Comment: baautiful but didnt work could you please give me full code